# I want to write java selenium code for picking the date from datepicker

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

```
@Given("^I choose destination to \"(.*?)\" on \"(.*?)\" from \"(.*?)\"  
with \"(.*?)\" or \"(.*?)\" or \"(.*?)\"$")
public void i_choose_destination_to_on_from_with_or_or(String where, String When, String departingfrom, String adults, String children, String infants) throws Throwable {
    driver.get("http://www.example.co.uk/");
    WebElement selectElement = driver.findElement(By.tagName("select"));
    Select selectObject = new Select(selectElement);
    selectObject.selectByVisibleText(where);
    Thread.sleep(200);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='fieldcalendar']//input[@class='datepicker']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='pika-lendar']//select[@class='pika-select pika-select-month']")).sendKeys("March");
    WebElement selectYearElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@class='pika-select pika-select-year']"));
    Select selectYearObject = new Select(selectYearElement);
    selectYearObject.selectByValue("2016");
    List<WebElement> dayField = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("button.pika-button.pika-day"));
    for (WebElement cell: dayField) {
        String tag = cell.getAttribute("data-pika-day");
        if (tag.equals("6")) {
            WebElement input = (new WebDriverWait(driver,15)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("button.pika-button.pika-day")));
            //below code not working
            input.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.pika-button.pika-day")).click();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Please refer this website.I tried with the following code but it's not
     working for clicking date in calendar. 
     It's working fine for month and  year.
     need help to fix it.Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to locate this button from itself. You already have this button in `input` variable but you using it to locate it again. You can only locate child elements that way. Simply do

```
input.click();
```

Or

```
(new WebDriverWait(driver,15)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("button.pika-button.pika-day"))).click();
```

> Edit

`ElementNotVisibleException` means the button you are trying to click is not visible. Try to use `visibilityOfElementLocated` in the expected conditions

```
(new WebDriverWait(driver,15)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("button.pika-button.pika-day"))).click();
```

If you need to scroll to the element to make it visible you can use `Actions` class

```
WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.pika-button.pika-day"));

Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(input).build().perform(); // this will simulate scroll to the button

(new WebDriverWait(driver,15)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(input)).click();
```

Comment: I tried both but got an exception as follows:  org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
(Session info: chrome=48.0.2564.97)
 (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353145 (343b531d31eeb933ec778dbcf7081628a1396067),platform=Windows NT 10.0 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 80 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf323ce037c5f92db6c1bba601c2ac43ad8', time: '2014-10-23

Comment: @NageshReddy I edit my answer, look under the "edit" section.